# Word for a person who learned something in the past, but is now back down to beginner level?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who learned something a long time ago and now is at the same level in that skill as a beginner would be?

Guy isn't a novice. He isn't a veteran either. He was proficient in the skill long time back and can quickly (faster than a beginner for sure) get to the same proficiency level again, given sufficient resources.

---

Update: I'm looking for a formal word. **Rusty** suggested by Dan is perfect. So is **old hand**. Is there a word that can used to describe the above person in a professional context?

Comment: Guy is ***rusty***.

Comment: @DanBron: I completely agree. Is there a formal substitute for *rusty*?

Comment: 'Out of practice' might work for you.

Comment: similar question:[Term for a newcomer, who has already had some knowledge?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280020/term-for-a-newcomer-who-has-already-had-some-knowledge), very similar question: [Easy is to beginner as medium is to](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294747/easy-is-to-beginner-as-medium-is-to) The following contains an extensive list [List of expertise levels from beginner to expert](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83832/list-of-expertise-levels-from-beginner-to-expert?lq=1)

Comment: But I'd say this older question answers the OP: [More than an intermediate but less so than an expert](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/more-than-an-intermediate-but-less-so-than-an-expert) But if I cast my superpower vote (!), the OP's question will automatically close..

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the OP wants to describe an old-timer who's forgotten more than the young 'uns have learnt (unfortunately including the job's skill-set in the *forgotten* part), but who can pick it up again quickly. Hence *rusty*.

Comment: If the future  "employee" had several years of experience in the trade, he is still *experienced*, if several years have passed since he was last employed, then I'd say "[formerly skilled](https://books.google.it/books?id=-eSwCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=%22formerly+skilled%22&source=bl&ots=R4g-xkmfHH&sig=9MF-f6HXajouiaTQKN0aIH3YATY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9x_uBqsXLAhUD3iwKHbdeAkU4ChDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22formerly%20skilled%22&f=false) / trained", "semi-skilled", or "in need of retraining". Is the person a labourer, an ex-player, an artisan, a paraprofessional? More context is needed!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I was looking for the part *had several years of experience in the trade, he is still experienced, if several years have passed since he was last employed, then I'd say "formerly skilled / trained", "semi-skilled", or "in need of retraining"*. You may post this as an answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: Except for being able to regain proficiency quickly, you could be talking about [*Algernon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowers_for_Algernon) (well, really Charlie).

Comment: Would _ neophyte_ do?

Comment: *old hand* doesn't imply anything about being out-of-practice; in fact, I would say it implies they're still an expert.

Comment: @Diti no, *neophyte* would mean they're completely new to it.

Comment: not actually a word but: renewbie

Comment: @Mr.Mindor right, renoob...

Comment: The appropriate definition of [rusty](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rusty?s=t) is not informal: "impaired through disuse or neglect"  *"My Latin is rusty."*

Comment: @DanBron: Though it is already pretty visible as the most up-voted comment, I think you should add *rusty* as an answer.

Comment: I notice that some of the answers cite the idea that in some professions, you can lose proficiency not because you forgot anything, but because the profession itself advanced and the standard of proficiency changed. You might want to clarify whether that phenomenon is within the scope of your question or outside of it.

Comment: @DavidK: I think it'll be better to have answers that mention the single words for either case. It will keep the question useful for more users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The OP has asked me to post my comment as an answer.

If the future employee had several years of experience in the trade, **he is still experienced**; if several years have passed since he was last employed, then I'd say [“formerly skilled”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-eSwCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22formerly+skilled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv-7jvtMjLAhUmnnIKHea5D-E4HhDoAQgkMAA#v=onepage&q=%22formerly%20skilled%22&f=false), “previously trained”, “semi-skilled”, or “in need of retraining”.

> If you remain an [software] engineer until retirement then you need to be prepared to constantly learn new tools and techniques in order to remain relevant. Generally speaking, you will need to be able to fully **retrain** yourself roughly every 4 to 6 years (while still working full-time). The only way to do that without burning out is to love what you do.

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-many-years-can-an-averagely-performing-software-engineer-survive-in-the-IT-industry-What-do-many-people-do-after-that-period)

Comment: The link is broken by the way. I reach to a page which is not available to me.

Comment: @displayName  Weird, it's working for me, and it's the same link in the comment as well. Page 171 in *Employment and Opportunity* By Geoffrey Payne. Try typing the expression "formerly skilled" in the search box. However it's [*formerly*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/formerly?) that I imagine interests you most.

Comment: Seems there are perhaps too many direct clicks from SE to google as there was an error message to that effect. copy/paste the url into a new tab worked.

Comment: The link didn't work for me either, unless it was opened in a new tab. Perhaps it would be good if the source was quoted and cited in the answer?

Comment: @displayName The link didn't work for me either, but Google allowed me to view the page once I changed the domain from `books.google.co.uk` to `books.google.com`.  [This is the link that worked for me.](https://books.google.com/books?id=-eSwCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22formerly+skilled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv-7jvtMjLAhUmnnIKHea5D-E4HhDoAQgkMAA#v=onepage&q=%22formerly%20skilled%22&f=false)  I don't know exactly how it works, but I think sometimes certain links to Google Books only work in some regions.

Answer (score 82):

In England we would simply say he was ***out of practice.***

This meets your requirements perfectly: it expresses that the person is not currently proficient, but that they used to be, and that their current lack of aptitude is simply a result of having not practised, rather than through any shortcomings that they might have. It is therefore very polite.

> **[out of practice:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/practice)** not currently proficient in a particular activity or skill through not having exercised or performed it for some time.
>
> *"he was out of practice at interrogation"*
>
> synonyms:  rusty, unpractised

<sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/practice) (accessed March 16, 2016)</sub>

Comment: This phrase is used in exactly the same way in America as well.

Answer (score 18):

This person can be called an **erstwhile** expert, which suggests that the person used to be proficient, but is currently not anymore.

> erstwhile - [former; of times past](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/erstwhile?s=t) (dictionary.com)

Comment: That's a pretty uncommon word though, a lot of people wouldn't understand it.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly uncommon.  I'd consider a native speaker who didn't know the word to be pretty poorly-read.  For instance, here are three NYT articles containing *erstwhile* from the past three months:

* http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/07/opinion/france-forfeits-its-own-values.html
* http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/17/fashion/grammy-awards-fashion.html
* http://www.nytimes.com/2016/03/04/fashion/paris-fashion-week-vetements-demna-gvasalia.html

Comment: That said, I'm not 100% on board with using "erstwhile" or "former" or anything of the kind here, because it doesn't really communicate *why* the person used to be an expert -- did the subject matter change?  Did he turn out to be a charlatan?  Has he died?

Answer (score 12):

One word often used is [*lapsed*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+lapsed).

This is particularly used for professions where certification is required to practice and a regular test or experience is required to retain the certificate.  A *lapsed* indivdual has the experience but must resit the examination to practice.

The word is also used in a religious context for people who no longer follow a particular church.

Answer (score 6):

A person **regressed** or experienced **regression.**

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, but you don't provide any explanation—authoritative or otherwise—of why _regressed/regression_ might be a good choice. To strengthen your answer, please consider adding a dictionary for one or both words, along with a citation of the source and, if possible, a link to it.

Answer (score 5):

***false beginner*** might fit what you're looking for.

> *If you are a beginner or a false beginner, you must acquire first the basic notions which will allow you to reach the intermediate level.*
>
> [onlinelearners.net](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/faux+d%C3%A9butant.html)
>
> *We also say **false beginner** for a language student who has forgotten much of what s/he previously learned.*
>
> *A **remedial learner** might be another way to express this.* (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/faux-d%C3%A9butant.875647/)

Comment: I've never heard that expression. Perhaps it's a UK term? I'm from the Midwest - USA.

Comment: @ElbyCloud Is Virginia Piedmont & Washington, DC located in the UK? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Rusty** (suggested by @Dan Bron) or **out of practice** (@Charon's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314004/163763)) both describe someone who was once skilled in a field, but has not used those skills and may need to **brush up** on them or to be **retrained** (@Mary-Lou A's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314054/163763)).

If the field requires some type of professional certification, which the person used to have, his or her certification may have **lapsed** (@Chenmunka's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314058/163763)) and he or she would need to be re-certified.

When the field itself is outdated, the person's skills are **antiquated** (@sthede's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314114/163763)), but the person may still be proficient.

These may all be used in professional contexts.

Answer (score 2):

If Guy is in the process of brushing up his skills in order to compete at his former level, we say he is *"going for/working towards* ***'a comeback'*** *"*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the trade, **uncertified** or perhaps **certifiable** might work.  These would both imply that knowledge exists, but proficiency is lacking or at least has not been tested.

Answer (score -1):

The persons skill set is **antiquated**.

**antiquated**:
old-fashioned or outdated.
"this antiquated central heating system"
synonyms:   outdated, out of date, outmoded, outworn, old, stale, behind the times, old-fashioned, anachronistic, old-fangled, antique, antediluvian, passé, démodé, obsolete;

Comment: There is nothing in the OP's question that implies either the *skill* or the *person* is out of date or antiquated. For example the last time I played the violin since about 30 years ago, and I certainly haven't forgotten *how* to do it, but I would need to do some serious practice if I started again. But there is nothing particularly "antiquated" about either myself, or the art of violin-playing.

Comment: Take the case of a computer programmer, perhaps the programmer learned how to make web pages 20 years ago, and used Notepad for all his development.  The programmer knows how to build a page, but the level at which the person develops for example is antiquated.  An understanding of the requirements, but an out-dated method of implementing or acting on those skills.  A wood-worker using a chisel instead of a router, his skill set could be called antiquated.  The person was referred to as:  'a person who learned something a long time ago'.  I think that implies the skills are old.

Answer (score -3):

Guy may well have perfectly-retained skills from a time
when the requirements were different.
Someone who was an excellent typist in 1980, for example, would need to
learn a variety of contemporary computer skills just to match a beginner now.

In this case, Guy's skills could be called **precursory**.

They are **precursors** — forerunners
or earlier versions — of
up-to-date skills.

> [*precursory*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/precursory) – adj. –
>   Preceding something in time, development, or position.
>
> [*precursor*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/precursor) – noun –
>   A person or thing that comes before another of the same kind; a forerunner.
>
> [oxforddictionaries.com]

As used at
[nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/02/23/news/for-the-world-of-ships-a-master-miniaturist.html):

> ... and the rebec, a three-stringed **precursor** of the violin.

A note of caution:  *Precursory* might actually be too formal because many
people will mistake it to only mean *undeveloped*.

Comment: All skills that can be improved are by definition precursors of the improved skills.  This says absolutely nothing about the regression.

Comment: The answer has been clarified